# can't access addActionListener method inside the createCell method in the table model

Tags: java, codenameone

i have created a table and in one of the rows there's an evaluate button and an image button once u click on one of them an Action should happen but the problem is once i created an Action Listener inside the createCell method it doesn't seem to function once i click

```
  Object[][] rows = new Object[articles.size()][];
    for (int iter = 0; iter < rows.length; iter++) {
        rows[iter] = new Object[]{
            articles.get(iter).getName(),
            0,
            articles.get(iter).getDescription(),
            articles.get(iter).getLabel(),
            articles.get(iter).getQuantity(),
            articles.get(iter).getRating(), 0
        };
    }

    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"name", "description", "Image", "label", "quantity", "rating", "rate"}, rows);
    Table table = new Table(model) {
        @Override
        protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {
            Button eval = new Button("Evaluate");
            Button img = new Button("See image");

            if (row > -1 && column == 2) {
                System.out.println("Value="+value.toString());
                return img;
            }
            if (row > -1 && column == 6) {
                return eval;
            }
            eval.addActionListener((ActionListener) (ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    System.out.println("click on eval");
            });
            img.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                           System.out.println("click on img");
                }
            });
            return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
            }
        };
        add(table);
```

Comment: Can u be more specific please i don't understand what u mean i opened the link and read the tutorial and still didn't find an explanation why the ActionListener is not working inside the createCell method

Comment: @Abra this is a Codename One question not a Swing question. Notice the use of Table and not JTable

Comment: it's a Codename one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
if (row > -1 && column == 6) {
    return eval;
}
```

Before the code that adds the action listener so that code isn't reached.

I suggest running in the debugger and placing breakpoint, this helps track issues such as this quickly.